# C++ Unexpected Multithreading Behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am working with multi-threading in C++ using a mutex. My code is below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

std::mutex mu;

void shared_print(string msg, int i) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mu);
    cout << msg << i << endl;
}

void function_1() {
    for (int i = 0; i > -3; i--)
        shared_print("Thread1: ", i);
}

int main() {
    std::thread thread1(function_1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        shared_print("Main: ", i);

    thread1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, the mutex will only allow access to a single resource at a time. So the mutex will be locked by the first thread that calls it (`Thread1`). When the `main` thread attempts to access the mutex, it is blocked until the mutex has been unlocked by `Thread1`. It will be unblocked once `cout` has executed upon which `main` will be allowed to execute.

I expect the result to be interleaving calls such as `Thread1, Main, Thread1, Main` etc.

However, instead I get the below result on standard out. The pattern remains the same for any number of iterations:

```
Thread1: 0
Thread1: -1
Thread1: -2
Main: 0
Main: 1
Main: 2
```

Comment: Why would it be interleaving? There is no ordering enforced by your code. If a thread still has CPU time, it can get the lock that it just released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First realize that the order of execution is non-deterministic, so what you got is perfectly valid--and the next time you run it, you might get a completely different order.

I increased the number of iterations for each thread to 32. Running that, the last few iterations looked like this:

```
Thread1: -22
Main: 22
Thread1: -23
Main: 23
Main: 24
Thread1: -24
Main: 25
Thread1: -25
Main: 26
Thread1: -26
Main: 27
Thread1: -27
Thread1: -28
Thread1: -29
Main: 28
Main: 29
Main: 30
Main: 31
Thread1: -30
Thread1: -31
```

So, sometimes we get interleaving, and other times we get short runs (4 was the longest in this case) coming from one thread. Other times I ran it, I got perfect interleaving, so the whole thing ran as one output from Thread 1 followed by one output from Main, and repeating.

Bottom line: your code is working as expected.